# React Router: Error when sending param (Cannot read property 'userID' of undefined)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to pass a parameter to a Component using React-Router, but I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'userID' of undefined`.

**Login.jsx** (from where the parameter is sent to the Router.jsx)

```
import React from 'react'
import Radium from 'radium'
import { Link, router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

class Login extends React.Component {

  loadTracks(username){
    browserHistory.push(`/track/${username}`);
  }

  render(){
    let _this = this;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={function(e){e.preventDefault(); _this.loadTracks(document.getElementById("username").value)}}>
          <input id="username" type="text"/><br/>
          <button key="submitButton" type="submit">YES LET'S GO!</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Radium(Login);
```

**Router.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

import Login from './Components/Login.jsx'
import App from './Components/App.jsx'
import Track from './Components/Track.jsx'

Meteor.startup(() => ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Login} />
    <Route path='/app' component={App}>
      <Route path='/track/:userID' component={Track} />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app-container'))
);
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleRoot } from 'radium'

import Track from './Track.jsx'

export default class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <StyleRoot>
        <Track />
      </StyleRoot>
    )
  }
}
```

**Track.jsx** (the file where the param is sent to)

```
import React from 'react'
import Radium from 'radium'
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

class Track extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.props.params.userID);
    return (
      //SOMETHING
    )
  }
}

export default Radium(Track);
```

Any suggestions of how to solve this?

Comment: In your routes, you name the param `userID`, but try to refer to it as `username` in your Track component. Is that part of the issue?

Comment: Oh, nice catch @DanPhillips, but that was not it. Still got the error :(

Comment: Also, if I just try to do `console.log(this.props.params)`,  I get `undefined`.

Comment: Try removing the `constructor` or use it like this `constructor(props){super(props);}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @dannyjolie. But it still does not work...

Comment: Ok, so I found out that if I place `<Route path='/track/:userID' component={Track} />` outside the `<Route path='/app' component={App}>` (like this: `<Route path='/' component={Login} /> <Route path='/track/:userID' component={Track} /> <Route path='/app' component={App} />`), it works. How can I make it work when the `Track`-route is a child of the `App`-route, like it is in the question?